# JS Sprite animation on Chrome

Tags: jquery, animation, sprite

I'm making some sprite animation (easter egg) on my site. Its working well on Mozilla. But on Chrome its not working. Problem is everytime I use $("img").attr('src', 'new_path') its downloading new image (not from cache). How I solve it?

Please open it on Mozilla then type "holycow", and you will see how it must work. Then open it on Chrome.

http://html5.maniac.mn/

Javascript: http://html5.maniac.mn/js/liukang.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way, sir. You need to make a sprite sheet and offset the background-position instead. Otherwise you'll get flickering in at least one browser. If you need an example I can update this answer.

Here's a sample of this in action:

http://www.wrightonwrong.com/

hover over the depressed stick figure guy. You can view the js source and any image assets to see how I did it here.

a slightly more elaborate version here:
http://www.innercirclestyles.com/

Comment: You meant all images from one action must contain in one image?

Comment: Essentially. It's not a requirement, but it is definitely better for performance. You create an image that has all frames of the animation in a line, ideally in equal spacing, and set that image as the background of an element. then instead of updating the img src you update the background-position of the containing element.

Comment: I almost understood your suggest. Thats why I used preloader. If you see /js/liukang.js file's bottom part, there are function creates images. I thought Chrome will use those images.

Comment: It still has to swap them. moving a background position is much less heavy since the image is already rendered.